# Get contents of a .gz file over SSH and pipe it to zcat and mysql

Tags: ssh, cat

I have a `recent.sql.gz` file on a remote server. What I try to accomplish is the following: I want to open the file, push the content over SSH to my local machine, use zcat to uncompress the content and pipe it to mysql. Something like this:

```
ssh user@remote 'cat recent.sql.gz' | zcat | mysql
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: oh well, ehm.. didn't test it. i thought it can't be that easy.

Comment: provided `recent.sql.gz` is in `HOME` dir of user on remote, and ssh work password less-ly, this should work.

Comment: Alright then :)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is

`ssh user@remote 'cat recent.sql.gz' | zcat | mysql`

Thank you to @Aley above :)

Comment: Unless there is a real reason to transfer the file compressed: `ssh user@remote 'gzip -c -d recent.sql.gz' | mysql`

Comment: I thought about that too.  Typically, CPU's and memory are faster than the network, and average sql is very compressible (if you're not storing pre-compressed blobs, of course).  So compressing, transferring, and uncompressing should (in year 2022) be faster than sending an uncompressed file across a network.  Future network tech may prove us wrong - but I wouldn't bet on it yet.